# mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to this and I am trying to insert data to multiple tables

```
$prisoner_insert = "INSERT INTO prisoner (givenName,middleName,lastName,nickname,presentAdd,permanentAdd,prisonno,age,
        gender,civilstatus,birthdate,birthplace,height,weight,build,eyecolor,haircolor,complexion,nationality,religion,acrno,
        education,occupation,motherName,fatherName,spouse,childno,nearestkin,relationkin,kinAdd,status) 

        VALUES ('$gname','$mname','$lname','$aname','$padd','$pedd','$pno','$age','$gender','$cstatus','$bdate','$bplace',
        '$height','$weight','$build','$ecolor','$hcolor','$complex','$nation','$relign','$acr','$edu','$occu','$mother','$father','$spouse',
        '$child','$kname','$krelation','$kaddress','$status')";

$offense_insert = "INSERT INTO offensedata (crime,crimedate,caseno,trialcourt,date_sentence,datetime_commited,imprisonment)
                    VALUES ('$c_com','$c_date','$c_caseno','$trialc','$d_commence','$dt_committed','$imprisonment')";


 if(mysqli_multi_query($prisoner_insert, $offense_insert)){                       

 echo "Inserted Successfully!";
}
else{

     echo "Error:" . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
```

I got the following error:

> mysqli_multi_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\jailbsystem\admin\admin_add.php

Comment: DO NOT use a multi query, use separate query calls with **prepared statements**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to pass `db link` at first parameter of `mysqli_multi_query();` as is in the code below.

Also you need to combine your sql queries the correct way. With `;` as delimeter of each command.

Removed previous variables `$prisoner_insert`, `$offense_insert` and replaced it with just one `$jail_sql`.

INSERT for `offensedata` is not being supplied with the required `prisoner_id` from the `prisoner` INSERT. As a fix, added LAST_INSERT_ID() as value for field `prisoner_id` in offensedata;

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` supplies the ID of the most recently auto-generated ID for that entire database connection.

**Updated Code:**

```
$jail_sql = "INSERT INTO prisoner (givenName,middleName,lastName,nickname,presentAdd,permanentAdd,prisonno,age,
        gender,civilstatus,birthdate,birthplace,height,weight,build,eyecolor,haircolor,complexion,nationality,religion,acrno,
        education,occupation,motherName,fatherName,spouse,childno,nearestkin,relationkin,kinAdd,status) 

        VALUES ('$gname','$mname','$lname','$aname','$padd','$pedd','$pno','$age','$gender','$cstatus','$bdate','$bplace',
        '$height','$weight','$build','$ecolor','$hcolor','$complex','$nation','$relign','$acr','$edu','$occu','$mother','$father','$spouse',
        '$child','$kname','$krelation','$kaddress','$status');";

$jail_sql .= "INSERT INTO offensedata (prisoner_id, crime,crimedate,caseno,trialcourt,date_sentence,datetime_commited,imprisonment)
                    VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID() , '$c_com','$c_date','$c_caseno','$trialc','$d_commence','$dt_committed','$imprisonment');";


 if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $jail_sql)){                       

 echo "Inserted Successfully!";
}
else{

     echo "Error:" . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
```

Comment: You better port that after to prepared statements to evade sql injections.

Comment: Datas were inserted successfully in prisoner table however in offensedata table I get an error

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jail_booking`.`offensedata`, CONSTRAINT `fkoffenseprisoner_id` FOREIGN KEY (`prisoner_id`) REFERENCES `prisoner` (`prisoner_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Can you pastebin table structure of `offensedata` ?

Comment: Also for prisoner

Comment: Add also in your `offensedata` `INSERT` string, add a value for `prisoner_id` column. Make sure the prisoner_id value also exists in prisoner table.

Comment: If I add new prisoner, can a value in prisoner_id in offensedata table be inserted automatically?
in offensedata table, the prisoner_id should be the same with the id in prisoner table.

this is ex of what it looks like https://ibb.co/iknbaS @KarloKokkak

Comment: You can just use LAST_INSERT_ID() to supply the value for prisoner_id in offensedata;